# When hovering over text, change the text and background image

Tags: javascript, css, function, hover

I am new to coding and wrapping my head around utilization of JavaScript it still hard for me.

My problem is that I have like a navigation menu, those  have one word in them. I want that when I hover over navigation menu background of the entire site changes corresponding to the navigation menu item I hovered over, and the navigation item changes it's content from one word to more words.

I tried searching on Google, YouTube and here on stackoverflow of course. I managed to get working code but it feels like a mess and bad practice and I wasn't able to implement good answers to my code or they were using ES5 JavaScript which differentiates from ES6 a lot.

Here are the things I tried:

1 . First thing i tried is to create a function with if statements. Didn't quite work. Probably because of my low understanding of JS.

2. I tried then to addEventListener to every navigation menu item individually. And that works, but it's a mess. Just blocks of copy / pasted code.
3. I tried then to create a function again and have *onmouseover = "function()"* inside of HTML but didn't work either.
4. Then I tried to do it over CSS but my inexperience started to show again it seems. I wasn't able to succeed in it with :before and :after either.

I have some example code here.

```
<div id='bckgimg'>

<div class="nav-container">
  <a href='/nav1' id='nav-nav1' class='nav'>NAV1</a>
  <a href='/nav2' id='nav-nav2' class='nav'>NAV2</a>
  <a href='/nav3' id='nav-nav3' class='nav'>NAV3</a>
  <a href='/nav4' id='nav-nav4' class='nav'>NAV4</a>
</div>
</div>

<style>

#bckgimg{
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200');
}

</style>

<script>

const nav1 = document.getElementById('nav-nav1');
const nav2 = document.getElementById('nav-nav2');
const nav3 = document.getElementById('nav-nav3');
const nav4 = document.getElementById('nav-nav4');
const bckgImg = document.getElementById("bckgimg");

// repeat this code 3 more times with nav2, nav3, nav4
// code bellow checks if <div> is hovered over and changes background image <div> + changes text of the <div>

navStories.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  bckgImg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/200')";
  navStories.innerHTML = "MY NAV 1 LONGER";
});

// if <div> is hovered out it returns the original picture to background <div> and original text of <div>

navStories.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  bckgImg.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200')";
  navStories.innerHTML = "NAV1";
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright figured it out! Took me whole day but I got it!

First of, on JSfiddle where it says *JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS)* you need to press on the arrow on the side and for *LOAD TYPE* choose *no wrap - bottom of body*.

Second, if you have code which has an error which is represented by red color by JSfiddle your whole directory (JavaScript directory in my case) won't run. Error in my code was that I just commented all the code I didn't need at the bottom with /* but didn't close it since I thought it wasn't important.

Third, the solution itself:

```js
// changed whole thing, which was my point. Reduced code from ~50 lines to two functions in 16 lines

// onHover function has a property of i which corresponds to numbers in html on onmouseover and out

// created arrays with IDs, what text and image should be after hovering
// i will correspond to numbers in html which in turn correspond to numbers in arrays

function onHover(i) {
  const array = ["nav-nav1", "nav-nav2", "nav-nav3", "nav-nav4"];
  const strings = ["MY NAV 1 LONGER", "MY NAV 2 LONGER", "MY NAV 3 LONGER", "MY NAV 4 LONGER"];
  const bckgUrls = ["url('https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/200", "url('https://picsum.photos/id/3/300/200')", "url('https://picsum.photos/id/4/300/200')", "url('https://picsum.photos/id/5/300/200')"];
  var idvar = document.getElementById(array[i]);
  idvar.innerHTML = `${strings[i]}`;
 document.getElementById("bckgimg").style.backgroundImage = `${bckgUrls[i]}`;
 }

// when hovering out from text do same like onHover just the reverse
// return values of navigation menu and background image to original

function outHover(i) {
  const array = ["nav-nav1", "nav-nav2", "nav-nav3", "nav-nav4"];
  const strings = ["NAV1", "NAV2", "NAV3", "NAV4"];
  var idvar = document.getElementById(array[i]);
  idvar.innerHTML = `${strings[i]}`;
 document.getElementById("bckgimg").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200')";
 }
```

```css
#bckgimg{
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200');
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='bckgimg'>

<!-- because we changed ON LOAD options now onmouseover and on mouseout will pull functions from JS -->

<div class="nav-container">
  <a onmouseover="onHover(0)" onmouseout="outHover(0)" href='/nav1' id='nav-nav1' class='nav'>NAV1</a><br>
  <a onmouseover="onHover(1)" onmouseout="outHover(1)" href='/nav2' id='nav-nav2' class='nav'>NAV2</a><br>
  <a onmouseover="onHover(2)" onmouseout="outHover(2)" href='/nav3' id='nav-nav3' class='nav'>NAV3</a><br>
  <a onmouseover="onHover(3)" onmouseout="outHover(3)" href='/nav4' id='nav-nav4' class='nav'>NAV4</a><br>
</div>
</div>
```